# Swift: create a infix operator for Optional values which provide default values when empty

Tags: ios, swift, operators, extension-methods, option-type

In relation to my last question (over here: [Swift where condition to check if a property is implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088462/swift-where-condition-to-check-if-a-property-is-implemented/) ) where I thought I was very clever by creating a protocol extension to provide a default value for nil or empty strings by using the following code, I now have another question. But first, heres the code:

```
protocol Emptyable {
    var isEmpty: Bool { get }
}

extension Optional where Wrapped: Emptyable {
    func orWhenNilOrEmpty<T: Emptyable>(_ defaultValue: T) -> T {
        switch(self) {
        case .none:
            return defaultValue
        case .some(let value) where value.isEmpty:
            return defaultValue
        case .some(let value):
            return value as! T
        }
    }
}

extension String: Emptyable {}
```

As you see i can now provide default values for optionals implementing the Emptyable protocol I defined. I did this to save the ever repeating code of this style (more about why I do this in the blog post mentioned in the other question):

```
if let unwrapped = optional, !unwrapped.isEmpty {
    myLabel.text = unwrapped
} else {
    myLabel.text = "Some Default Text"
}
```

Now for the purpose of learning and becoming a better developer, I thought it could be fun to create a new operator to call the orWhenNilOrEmpty function for me like so:

```
let optionalString: String? = nil
let actualString: String = some ??? "Hello World"
```

So I tried this:

```
infix operator ???: DefaultPrecedence
extension Optional where Wrapped: Emptyable {
    static func ???<T>(left: T?, right: T) -> T {
        return left.orWhenNilAndEmpty(right)
    }
}
```

But I get this error and I don't really understand why. I hope you can clarify the issue and explain what I'm doing wrong:

```
generic parameter 'Wrapped' could not be inferred
```

Comment: it is already exists, `??`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was trying to use a generic `T` in the function declaration. Also `DefaultPrecedence` wasn't the best choice. This is how I now solved it and how it works:

```
protocol Emptyable { var isEmpty: Bool { get } }

infix operator ???: NilCoalescingPrecedence

extension Optional where Wrapped: Emptyable {
    func orWhenNilOrEmpty(_ defaultValue: Wrapped) -> Wrapped {
        switch(self) {
        case .none:
            return defaultValue
        case .some(let value) where value.isEmpty:
            return defaultValue
        case .some(let value):
            return value
        }
    }

    static func ???(left: Wrapped?, right: Wrapped) -> Wrapped {
        return left.orWhenNilOrEmpty(right)
    }
}
```

Now all I have to do is implement `Emptyable` where ever I want and then I can use `???` to get a not empty value from any optional:

```
extension String: Emptyable {}
let notEmptyString = nilOrEmptyOptionalString ??? "Meaningful default value"
```